# My pc is not showing ad-hoc option

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, ad-hoc-network

I have windows 7 ultimate. I want to connect my pc's internet to my android mobile but there is no option of ad-hoc in control panel(network & internet). I also tried downloading virtual router but after installing it's showing that service not running. Plz help.....

Answer (score 0):

[How to share your connection](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/turn-windows-wifi-hotspot-share-internet-connection/)

You can find there how you can do it with windows, but If I'm not wrong, this is not working for Android. Android not support computers AD-hoc. You need router for that

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is an option like that to being with, if you want to connect your mobile, so you  can use your mobile as an access point which is what I assume you are asking you need to simply connect your phone to your computer with a USB wire that comes with it then simply look for a "tethering" option guide which relates to your phone model, i.e. Android or iphone